# Can I use `netstat` to find adware, spyware, malware or ransomware?

Tags: internet, malware, canonical, netstat

First off I ran `netstat -a` to list all but it's 1,000 lines of 80+ chars / line and won't fit into a question. So I narrowed it down to `netstat -l -e` to list connections that are "listening" to my internet connection.

## `netstat -l -e` Output:

```
$ netstat -l -e
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      
tcp        0      0 dell:domain             *:*                     LISTEN      root       22501      
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                                 Me         6099032    
udp        0      0 *:mdns                  *:*                                 avahi      20093      
udp        0      0 *:42320                 *:*                                 avahi      20095      
udp        0      0 *:55304                 *:*                                 nobody     6096007    
udp        0      0 dell:domain             *:*                                 root       22500      
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                *:*                                 root       6091056    
udp        0      0 *:ipp                   *:*                                 root       5216701    
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                              Me         6099033    
udp6       0      0 [::]:mdns               [::]:*                              avahi      20094      
udp6       0      0 [::]:57704              [::]:*                              avahi      20096      
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24329    /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     12608    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30872    @/tmp/.ICE-unix/2585
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26927    /run/user/1000/keyring/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30821    /run/user/1000/keyring/pkcs11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20701    /sys/fs/cgroup/cgmanager/sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30986    /run/user/1000/pulse/native
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1153703  /run/user/1000/pulse/cli
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2303008  @Me-com.canonical.Unity.Master.Scope.files.T174165901748652
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21329    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2303016  @Me-com.canonical.Unity.Scope.files.T174166293059520
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24726    /var/run/NetworkManager/private-dhcp
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25175    @/tmp/dbus-2IgIS5GS9B
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21330    /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27881    /tmp/ssh-Y2H8jyF8xBOV/agent.2502
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26969    /home/Me/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30873    /tmp/.ICE-unix/2585
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     24397    @/tmp/dbus-ciisbyQXHo
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26572    /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.KSH5A2/SingletonSocket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     691516   @/tmp/dbus-BCetHWrk4L
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2303007  @Me-com.canonical.Unity.Master.Scope.applications.T174165894531763
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12591    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12596    /run/systemd/fsck.progress
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12609    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     26932    @/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/2381
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2300330  @Me-com.canonical.Unity.Scope.scopes.T174169866065693
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21636    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21637    /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21638    /run/snapd.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21639    /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21640    /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21641    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     21642    /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2300329  @Me-com.canonical.Unity.Scope.applications.T17416986049498
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     29796    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-NdbJULTU
```

**Note:** I've replaced my Linux user ID with "Me" in the listing above.

I'm a little concerned that "Canonical" the manufacturer of "Ubuntu" is listening to my internet in many places. I don't recall big bold adverts of that happening nor ways of turning that "feature" off. I do have crash reporting turned on so maybe that is the reason. A detailed explanation in an answer would be appreciated though.

**Are there known spyware / malware agents I can see using netstat?**

Additionally can `netstat` help me track down internet performance blockers and kill a connection or two hundred? For example I see `snapd` is "listening" and just read it's a [performance hog](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328152) at times. Snapd is installed by default in **16.04** but I've never used it. I'll be researching it further and removing it.

---

## Random snippets of `netstat -a`

As mentioned using `netstat -a` generates over 1,000 lines of output that won't fit into a 32KB AU question. Here are some random "snippets" of the full list to give you an idea of what appears.

### From the middle

```
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    6091044  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28317    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     26391    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29087    @/tmp/dbus-ciisbyQXHo
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7523056  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     41964    @/tmp/dbus-ciisbyQXHo
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     36047    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     31024    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25186    @/tmp/dbus-2IgIS5GS9B
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     4258027  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6835290  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     692478   @/tmp/dbus-BCetHWrk4L
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     27314    @/tmp/dbus-2IgIS5GS9B
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29077    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1033729  @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     42812    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     29806    @/tmp/ibus/dbus-NdbJULTU
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6952286  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     161597   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     39839    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     33256    
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    33883
```

### From the bottom

```
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    29074    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     55854    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28997    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     21657    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     28055    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24441    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25875    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     23525    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     691504   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25897    @/tmp/dbus-ciisbyQXHo
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     30179
```

Forgive me if this question is rudimentary. I've just begun examining internet "connection stuff" and will look like a complete novice compared to those paid to work in this field.

Comment: I can't think of any way to check the safety of all connections, I guess you can only look for a known threat based  on its signatures.

Comment: @Ravexina good point. Do you know of a database that lists known threats? I could do some sort of lookup from my list to the database then. But I guess **good** anti-virus programs do that already right?

Comment: Yeah, security suites does that automatically based on their database or sometimes using their proactive and behavioral detections. I'm not aware of any database of known threats, you should know what you are exactly looking for, do a little bit research about it to find out how that works and if you're a victim of that malware. a starting point might be a [CVE list](https://cve.mitre.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The first time someone runs netstat it's a shocking experience.  It seems like every creepy web site on the planet is watching your every move.  And the reality is not that far from that perception.

Much of this connectivity is relatively benign.  And a few of the connections are actually helpful, such as OS update connections.  I would not be at all concerned about "Canonical connections" that are part of the Ubuntu software update model.  Further, you will quickly find that trying to kill or block these hundreds of connections is futile.

You'll find that except for blatant port attacks, most of the connections you see via netstat originate from your web browser.  You can control this to some degree but bear in mind that the more stuff you block, the more problems you will have when trying to do something useful on your web browser.

uBlock is a browser plugin that will drastically reduce the number of connections you see but will also reduce the functionality of your browser
s ability to engage with various sites.  Tightening up your environment versus being able to do real work is a constant balancing act.

Welcome to the Network Wild West :)

Comment: "Network Wild West" is good but "World Wide Web Wild West" is a better tongue-twister :).  `uBlock` sounds interesting and I'll research it later.

Comment: The uBlock author includes a lengthy set of lists that can be added to the blocking mechanism.  I find that FF works relatively well using the OOB uBlock settings.  The tool is very similar to PeerBlocker in the Microsoft World except the PB works for all connections not just those originating from a browser.  ClamAV is the best virus detector I know of for *NIX but you may find it to be disappointing.

Comment: Apparently there are two uBlocks. Which one are you talking about?: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14335190

Comment: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock

Comment: Thanks. Your link spells out the other one which is should be avoided: "***The donations sought by the individual behind ublock.org ("to keeps uBlock development possible", a misrepresentation) are not benefiting any of those who contributed most to create uBlock Origin (developers, translators, and all those who put efforts in opening detailed issues). For the differences between uBlock Origin and uBlock, see the unbiased Wikipedia article.***"